# Android In-app purchasing: Paid disabling of ads in your app kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ads

I want to add to my app the ability to disable in-app ads forever. I use google AdMob. It is important that it works so that it is like a subscription, that is, if the application is reinstalled, the subscription is not lost.
I have created a new activity where I have a button where I want to implement a drop-down menu from the play market where I will need to pay the subscription price.

> Activity class

```
class adverticement: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.adverticement)
    }
}
```

> XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/advertBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/advert1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Here is an example of an activity where I use advertising in the form of a banner, just as I have on other activities

```
lateinit var mAdViewAccessories : AdView //adMob banner
class accessories: AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.accessories)
        supportActionBar?.subtitle = getString(R.string.accessoriesTitle)
        loadBannerAd()
    }
    private fun loadBannerAd() {
        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

        mAdViewAccessories = findViewById(R.id.adView)
        val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
        mAdViewAccessories.loadAd(adRequest)

        mAdViewAccessories.adListener = object: AdListener() {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I disable ads?

Comment: One solution is to create two different layouts one with the ad banner and one without.

Comment: Check if the purchase is made, and if so, don’t call your function that loads banner ads. What are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 XML files one with ads and one without with adding if statement in setContentView(R.layout.accessories)

Comment: It would be much less XML duplication to keep track of across two layouts if you simply keep one layout and hide the ad view when not using it.

Comment: if I do this, then reinstalling the application will reset the settings, and I want them to depend on the subscription in google play

Comment: I want to check if the subscription is purchased from the user